# Netlogo - Create only one turtle per patch

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to create turtles in an office space area where designated grey patches represent their cubicles. However, when the turtles are created some overlap on top of each other within a cubicle.

How can I ensure only one turtle is created per cubicle? (find the code under ***)

This is the code I have:

```
breed [programmers programmer]
globals []

patches-own [
  a-space
  b-space
  c-space
  d-space
  a-cubicle
  b-cubicle
  c-cubicle
  d-cubicle
  cubicle?]

programmers-own [
  speed
  team-name
  motivation
  myCubicle
  teammates
  projects
  counter ]

to setup-environment
  ask patches with [ pycor mod 2 = 0 and pxcor = -16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pycor mod 2 = 0 and pxcor = 16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pxcor mod 2 = 0 and pycor = -16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pxcor mod 2 = 0 and pycor = 16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pycor = 0]   [ set pcolor red ]
  ask patches with [ pxcor = 0]   [ set pcolor red ]
  ask patches [
    set a-space patches with [(pxcor > -14) and (pxcor < 0) and (pycor > 0) and (pycor < 14)]
    set b-space patches with [(pxcor < 14) and (pxcor > 0) and (pycor > 0) and (pycor < 14)]
    set c-space patches with [(pxcor < 14) and (pxcor > 0) and (pycor < 0) and (pycor > -14)]
    set d-space patches with [(pxcor > -14) and (pxcor < 0) and (pycor < 0) and (pycor > -14)]
    set a-cubicle patches with [(pycor mod 2 = 0) and (pxcor mod 2 = 0) and (pxcor >= -16) and (pycor <= 16) and (pxcor < 0) and (pycor > 0)]
    set b-cubicle patches with [(pycor mod 2 = 0) and (pxcor mod 2 = 0) and (pxcor <= 16) and (pycor <= 16) and (pxcor > 0) and (pycor > 0)]
    set c-cubicle patches with [(pycor mod 2 = 0) and (pxcor mod 2 = 0) and (pxcor <= 16) and (pycor >= -16) and (pxcor > 0) and (pycor < 0)]
    set d-cubicle patches with [(pycor mod 2 = 0) and (pxcor mod 2 = 0) and (pxcor >= -16) and (pycor >= -16) and (pxcor < 0) and (pycor < 0)]   ]
  ask patches with [pcolor = grey] [set cubicle? true]
end

to setup-programmers
  create-programmers Number_Of_Programmers [
    set shape "person"
    ask n-of (Number_Of_Programmers / 4) programmers [set team-name "A"]
    ask n-of (Number_Of_Programmers / 4) programmers [set team-name "B"]
    ask n-of (Number_Of_Programmers / 4) programmers [set team-name "C"]
    ask n-of (Number_Of_Programmers / 4) programmers [set team-name "D"]

    ; *** WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO WOULD GO HERE ***
    ask programmers with [team-name = "A"]  [ set color blue] if other turtles-on patch-here [ move-to one-of a-cubicle with [cubicle? = true] set myCubicle patch-here]
    ask programmers with [team-name = "B"] [ set color green move-to one-of b-cubicle with [cubicle? = true] set myCubicle patch-here]
    ask programmers with [team-name = "C"] [ set color pink move-to one-of c-cubicle with [cubicle? = true] set myCubicle patch-here]
    ask programmers with [team-name = "D"] [ set color yellow move-to one-of d-cubicle with [cubicle? = true] set myCubicle patch-here]
    ask programmers [set teammates programmers with [color = [color] of myself]]
    set projects (list)
    set motivation 100
    set counter 0
    ]
end

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  setup-environment
  setup-programmers
end

to go
  lose-or-gain-motivation
  socialize
  complete-program
  tick
end
```

Comment: Please use code formatting (the {} icon) not quotes to show code in your question. I edited it so you can see the difference. Also, you should only show the code that is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different ways to create turtle agents in NetLogo. If you want want no more than one turtle in a patch, the easiest way to do so is to select a subset of patches (using `n-of XXX patches`) and ask them to `sprout` turtles. In your case, something like this might work:

Replace `create-programmers Number_Of_Programmers`

with

```
ask n-of Number_Of_Programmers patches with [cubicle?]
[ sprout-programmers 1
```

Comment: I tried that and I got "SPROUT expected this input to be a number, but got a turtle agentset instead"

Then I tried deleting programmers:


>[sprout 1

But then I got "You can't use SHAPE in a patch context, because SHAPE is turtle/link-only." for



>set shape "person"

Comment: see revised - was missing a dash